# How to remove duplicate in a list while the element is an array?

Tags: java

Why does the Java code return `false`?

```
List list = new ArrayList();
int[][] arr = {{-1, -1, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
list.add(arr[0]);
list.add(arr[1]);
int[] temp = {-1, 0, 1};
return list.contains(temp);
```

And when the elements in the list are arrays, how do I remove the duplicate then?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you really want contains to work you need to use comparable on your custom array list. And dups you need to create a new list and loop through old or put everything in a hashmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays don't override the implementation of `Object`'s `equals`, so, since `list.contains()` uses `equals` to determine if an element appears in the `List`, it will only return true if you are searching for the exact array object you added to the `List`. Therefore `list.contains(arr[1])` will return true, but `list.contains(temp)` won't, since `temp` and `arr[1]` are different objects (even though they contain the exact same elements).

You can use a `List<List<Integer>` instead of a `List<int[]>` in order for `list.contains()` to function as you expect (since the common implementations of the `List` interface do override `Object`'s `equals`).